# Jquery slideDown not working right away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is click function that search area will be slide down right under header. I made this with jQuery slideDown. But I can see that slideDown function is not working right away, It seem like waiting 1 second then slide down.

It is not a big problem, but this is bother me.

Is there any solution?

or this is just how slideDown function work?

Below is my code for reference:

```js
/*header function*/
function showHeaderSearch_PC() {
  $('.search_area').slideDown(260);
  $('#search_btn_pc').fadeOut(150, function(){
    $('#search_close_btn_pc').fadeIn(150);
  });
}
function hideHeaderSearch_PC() {
  $('.search_area').slideUp(260);
  $('#search_close_btn_pc').fadeOut(150, function(){
    $('#search_btn_pc').fadeIn(150);
  });
}
function showHeaderAllMenu() {
  $('.all_menu_area').slideDown(400);
  $('#all_menu_btn').fadeOut(150, function(){
    $('#all_menu_close_btn').fadeIn(150);
  });
}
function hideHeaderAllMenu() {
  $('.all_menu_area').slideUp(400);
  $('#all_menu_close_btn').fadeOut(150, function(){
    $('#all_menu_btn').fadeIn(150);
  });
}


$(function(){//PC header search function
  $('#search_btn_pc').click(function(){
    hideHeaderAllMenu();
    setTimeout(function(){ showHeaderSearch_PC();}, 400);
  });
  $('#search_close_btn_pc').click(function(){
    hideHeaderSearch_PC();
  });
});
$(function(){//PC header all menu function
  $('#all_menu_btn').click(function(){
    hideHeaderSearch_PC();
    setTimeout(function(){ showHeaderAllMenu();}, 270);
  });
  $('#all_menu_close_btn').click(function(){
    hideHeaderAllMenu();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Relevant code belongs directly into your question.

Comment: I'm assuming this is not "your" web page?   A simple look at the event handler shows this: `setTimeout(function(){ showHeaderSearch_PC();}, 400);`  - there's a timeout of 0.4 s before showing the header panel.  Remove the setTimeout or change it to 4.

Comment: i think your problem may be 'setTimeout(function(){ showHeaderSearch_PC();}, 400);' in '$('#search_btn_pc').click'; remove the settimeout should fix it

Comment: After edit, the problem is *still*: `setTimeout(function(){ showHeaderSearch_PC();}, 400);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you are using "slideDown" function with some value such as `slideDown(500);`

If you don't pass any value like `slideDown()`, it would slide down immediately

Comment: The parameter to slideDown is how long it takes, not a delay before it starts.

Comment: I believe, it's taking a minute or so to slide down which herbione was quoting as a delay.

Comment: `slideDown()` (without parameters) is the equivalent of `slideDown(400)`.  But it may have been (5000) and misinterpreted, yes.